# Regarding memory leaks and correct object management (Android / Java)

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, resources

What is the correct way to handle objects within Android (Java)?

What I mean is, lets say I have a **Splashscreen** class and then I create an object from this class.  Something like:

```
SplashScreen mySplash = new SplashScreen();
```

I then, within my **onCreate** method, display this splashscreen, like so:

```
loading_dialog.setContentView(mySplash);
loading_dialog.show();
```

....within the splashscreen I have bitmaps that are created.

Once everything has loaded, I finally get rid of the splash screen like so:

```
  loading_dialog.dismiss();
```

So, the splashscreen is no longer a requirement.

What is the correct way to proceed now with regards to handling this redundant object?

Should I be doing something like:

```
mySplash.myBitmap.recycle();
mySplash.myBitmap = null;
mySplash = null;
```

Or maybe just

```
mySplash = null;
```

If I do this, does it mean that everything within mySplash (Bitmaps etc) will also be set to null?

Just not sure which of the above is required,  or indeed, if neither is a good idea. Currently, I'm not doing anything, which I'm sure isn't right.

Also, and this is related, what happens if I also want to display this splashscreen if the user presses 'home' and then re-launches the app?  If I've gotten rid of it, then I'm in trouble.

Glad for any advise.

Comment: One of the main advantages of Java was relieving the programmer from having to actively manage memory. Let the garbage collector do its job.

Comment: Hi @MarsAtomic, thanks for the comment.  I must admit, I don't fully understand the GC.  Plus as this is a game running on low-resource devices, I want to free up memory where I can.  Are you saying I should just leave well alone and not recycle the bitmap or set the object to null?  If I don't set the object to null, will it still be a candidate for collection?  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [official Android doc on optimization](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html). I particularly like this line: "Before you start optimizing, make sure you have a problem that you need to solve."

Comment: Thanks @MarsAtomic, I've read that, and yeah I know that early / over-optimisation is the rout of all evil!  However, on a certain (low-end) tablet device I'm getting a bit of unresponsiveness (when pausing and relaunching app a few times, playing it for a while etc), so I'm trying to work out if it's memory related!